# How can I cause pods to start immediately when space opens up in a pod-limited Kubernetes namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

I wish to run a large (100-1000) number of deployments (each of size 1 pod) in a namespace with a small number of available pods (let's say 10 is the podLimit).

Is there a simple way to cause waiting deployments to start as soon as there is space (given the podLimit) to start new pods?

Essentially I would like behavior like a queue of pods into a pool of available pod spaces, without unnecessary delays, and without having to implement the orchestration myself.

I have created the large number of deployments in my namespace all at once, and I notice that the first few tens of deployments are relatively prompt to start as soon as previous deployments are terminated, however after a while, I see longer and longer (5-15 minutes) periods of dead time between all running pods going down and new deployments starting up. I'm fuzzy on the retry logic but I presume there is something like an exponential backoff happening as the pods attempt to start.

Comment: I've also run into trouble where the Kubernetes-internal controllers just get backed up (the times I've hit it, more around Jobs than Deployments, but a similar problem).  What you're describing sounds a little more like a job queue; could you use a smaller number of long-running Deployments, backed with something like RabbitMQ to send along the work to do?